# Trying to instantiate a DS3231 real-time clock within a library

Tags: library

I'm trying to write a library encapsulating things that I do with a DS3231 real time clock. I have managed to compile a sketch using the library, but it apparently blows up when attempting to call clock methods such as `getTime()`.

Header:

```
// JBP_DS3231.h
#ifndef __JBP_DS3231_h__
#define __JBP_DS3231_h__

#include <SD.h>
#include "DS3231.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

class JBP_DS3231
{
  public:
    JBP_DS3231();
    String TimeStamp();
  private:
    DS3231* _realTimeClock;
};

#endif
```

cpp:

```
#include <JBP_DS3231.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include "DS3231.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

JBP_DS3231::JBP_DS3231() {
  String thisTime = "";

  _realTimeClock = &DS3231(SDA, SCL); 

  Serial.println("About to try to get time from RTC."); // Last line we hear from.

  thisTime = _realTimeClock->getTimeStr();
  Serial.print("Time in constructor is: ");
  Serial.println(thisTime);
}

String JBP_DS3231::TimeStamp() {
  String timeStamp = "";

  Serial.println("In TimeStamp().");
  timeStamp = _realTimeClock->getDateStr(FORMAT_LONG, FORMAT_MIDDLEENDIAN, '/');
  Serial.print("Value of timestamp is: ");
  Serial.println(timeStamp);
  timeStamp.concat(" ");
  timeStamp.concat(_realTimeClock->getTimeStr());
  Serial.println(timeStamp);

  return timeStamp;
}
```

Script:

```
const String WHO_AM_I = "JBP_DS3231_library_test.ino";
const    int VERSION = 0;

#include <JBP_DS3231.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  AnnounceAwakening();

  JBP_DS3231 johnsRTC;
  Serial.println(johnsRTC.TimeStamp());
}

void loop() {
  return;
}

void AnnounceAwakening() {
  Serial.print("Sketch ");
  Serial.print(WHO_AM_I);
  Serial.print(" version ");
  Serial.print(VERSION);
  Serial.println(".");
  Serial.println("");
}
```

Comment: Define "blows up"...?

Comment: If all you want to do is to enhance what the existing DS3231 library can do I suggest you just extend the class (create your own class which inherits the existing class) and add your own functions to it.

Comment: Also, you will have to provide a link to the DS3231 library you are using. I found at least 3, and none of them appear to be the one you are using (judging by the constructors).

Comment: Library: http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/library.php?id=73

Comment: "blows up" means that no subsequent statements are executed after the first call to _realTimeClock->getDateStr().

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be providing a pointer to a constructor, not to an object.  Either create a *new* object with `new`, or instantiate the object separately and provide the pointer to the object:

```
_realTimeClock = new DS3231(SDA, SCL);
```

Better still, extend the existing class and implement your own methods:

```
clsss JBP_DS3231 : public DS3231 {
    public:
        JBP_DS3231(uint8_t d, uint8_t c) : DS3231(d, c) {
            String thisTime = "";
            Serial.println("About to try to get time from RTC."); // Last line we hear from.

            thisTime = getTimeStr();
            Serial.print("Time in constructor is: ");
            Serial.println(thisTime);
        }

        String TimeStamp() {
            String timeStamp = "";

            Serial.println("In TimeStamp().");
            timeStamp = getDateStr(FORMAT_LONG, FORMAT_MIDDLEENDIAN, '/');
            Serial.print("Value of timestamp is: ");
            Serial.println(timeStamp);
            timeStamp.concat(" ");
            timeStamp.concat(getTimeStr());
            Serial.println(timeStamp);

            return timeStamp;
        } 
};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    JBP_DS3231 myRTC(SDA, SCL);
    Serial.println(johnsRTC.TimeStamp());
}

void loop() {
}
```

(Note: untested)

Comment: For what I'm doing, extending the source class seems to be logical. I will attempt and report back, thank you.

Comment: Majenko, the example you gave is not in the form of a library. I attempted a few variations on; this gives me error: expected primary-expression before ',' token.

JBP_DS3231.h

    class JBP_DS3231 : public DS3231 {
      public:
        JBP_DS3231(uint8_t, uint8_t) : DS3231(uint8_t, uint8_t);

JBP_DS3231.cpp

    JBP_DS3231::JBP_DS3231(uint8_t _SDA, uint8_t _SCL) : DS3231(_SDA, _SCL) {